# Designing a curve that inverts

Tags: graphing-functions, inverse, curves

**Background:**

I am trying to come up with a formula for gradually increasing difficulty in my game.

The game randomly chooses objects based on weights. The more frequently you get complex objects the harder that level is.

**Problem**

I want to shift these weights as the level increases so that the game gradually gets more difficult but i also want earlier levels to not have any complex items at all and later levels to have only complex items. See an example of the kind of result im hoping for below

**Solution??**

I've been using https://www.transum.org/Maths/Activity/Graph/Desmos.asp
to plot a curved graph, my original thinking is if it gets thinner then inverts with l, then i've got the right solution. But now that i've achieved that:

```
y\ =\ \left(\left(\frac{x+w}{l-0.5}\cdot\frac{x+w}{l+0.5}\right)\right)
```

[image]
[image]
It doesn't feel right at all and i'm slowly losing my will to live. I originally tried with Sin and Cos but i dont want the curve to come back round. So then i thought powers make the most sense.

I have added a table of my ideal output where l goes from 0 to 1 (im hoping to make it a percentage so that i can play with the number of levels)

[image]

Comment: Have you considered a function like inverse tangent? With some modifiers it can range from $0$ to $1$ over an input range...  Similarly, you can use $\sin$ by modifying the input range and output range so that the outputs are monotonic.

Comment: Can you verify that this is the mathematical question you want answered? You have an input $\ell$ that goes from $0$ (first level) to $1$ (last level), and you have a random number generator that outputs real numbers $r$ between $0$ and $1$ uniformly. You want a function of $\ell$ and $r$ such that the distribution of values (as $r$ varies) mimics the table of values at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Hi @gregmartin there is no random number generator in this part of the logic. Just the two variables level and weight. At level 1 weight 1 will give the highest value while weight max (in the table 5) will give the lowest value. As level increases however the inverse will become true

Answer (score 1):

Since your level index can start at $1$, I recommend the weight function $f(x)=1-\frac 1x$ as a starting point.  Then your weight starts at $0$ and increases to asymptotically near $1$.